# Behavior or Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I was writing a random piece of code and it is bothering me as to why the output is 100000000 in this case:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    int[] array = {1};
    System.out.print(array[100000000]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
    }

}
```

Why does it print 100000000 and where can I read more about this behavior? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to access an array element at an index that is greater than (or equal to) the length of the array. [This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4)

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException#getMessage()` seemingly returns a `String` representing the index you tried to access.

Comment: I was expecting it to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I ignored the fact that I was just printing the message in the exception. Thank you this was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Because that is what the message property of the exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown is set to. Try adding     e.printStackTrace(); in the your catch block and it will print something like :

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000000
    at com.xxx.SomeTest.main(SomeTest.java:<< line number >>)